# How to get Java 19 to recognize 'record' keyword

Tags: java, java-record

I am using jdk 19 and want to make a record class for my Java project.

[image: jdk 19]

When I declare the class Person:

```
public record Person (String name) {}
```

I get the error

> 'class' or 'interface' expected

I don't understand why it will not let me use the record keyword.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Record was introduced in Java 14. The code works for me but I'm using java 17. Do you have the module language level changed?

Comment: yes, you must select at least Project language level 16 (it is even listed as `16 - Records, ...`) || @matt correct, it was introduced in 14, but as preview feature (up to including Java 15) - not sure how that can be enabled in InteliJ (`--enable-preview` when using the standard command line tools)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) feature arrived in [Java 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_16).

Project language level is selected to be 15, why didn't you change?